# Creating multiple select populated by js array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Ok this is a bit complicated. Basically I populate a select with an array. Then, I want to create another select, and populate it with the same array again. I believe that the populate function is not called properly when a new select is created, but I cannot find when to call it, to populate the created select.

1st: I query my db to get some member names, and use json_encode my resulting array, to create a json array.

```
    $result_array = Array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result_array[] = $name;
    }
    $json_array = json_encode($result_array);
```

then I echo that array to a javascript array, and populate a select tag with the result. All this happens on window load.

```
<script>
    var members = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
    function populate()
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById('members');
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        members.forEach(function(member, index) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = member;
            opt.value = member;
            fragment.appendChild(opt);
        });
        sel.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    window.onload = populate;
</script>
```

The html div containing the select:

```
<div id="Members">
    <select id="members"></select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="+" onClick="addInput('Members'); populate();">
```

and then I use another script to create more divs

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 3;

    function addInput(divName)
    {
        if (counter == limit)  
        {
            var message = document.getElementById("linkLimit");
            message.innerHTML = "Maximum amount of links reached";
        }
        else
        {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "<select id='members'></select>";
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            counter++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, the resulting selects are never actually populated. I believe that the populate function is not called properly, but I cannot find when to call it, to populate the created select.

---

Alternatively, for a static amount of select inputs, I tried doing

```
<div id="Members">
    <select id="members" name="members"></select>
    <select id="members1" name="members"></select>
    <select id="members2" name="members"></select>
</div>
```

<s>but again, only the first select is populated</s>

By using a for loop and giving members, members1, members2 through an array, all three lists are populated, however, this is not so functional, since I can't know how many members the user will want to select

Comment: If `members` is a JSON-encoded array you presumably - apart from anything else - need to parse it, with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), before it can be used, `members = JSON.parse(<?php echo $json_array; ?>);`?

Comment: @DavidThomas this is working fine, my select has names as needed. I also tried multiple selects but nope....

Comment: You can only have 1 element per page with any given id, so the else block in your `addInputs` function will cause problems. You'd want to call the function in that block of code, after you'd altered it(the function) to be able to work on any element, instead of being hard-coded to work with an object with the id of `members`.